# Performance analysis for java application

Tags: performance

I want to do a performance measurement of my application and would like to be able to configure the stats for specific module like (enable for specific module and disable for some) and I want to measure things like memory usage, threads, average band width etc..

Can any one suggest something please, I am new to this. I think Visual VM is good but it doesnot support configuring for different modules.

Does Perf4j or Admin4j work here? any one has used these before?

Comment: I honestly think that in this regard Java is no different from languages like C or C++ meaning that each platform offers 1 or more than 1 JVM implementations, so if you want to profile your application you have to deal with a considerable amount of JVMs out there. Also the situation is a little bit worst in this regard because you will create only a jar, you have no assurance that the user will use the JVM that you are targeting.

Comment: What if I am the only one measuring the performance and I have the code on my machine? not some one else measuring my code?

Comment: Is there any API like log4j do measure the performance?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but probably this is what you are looking for: Java Management Extensions (JMX) API

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/